# Value from hidden field in Panel ASP.NET has empty value after Link button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, panel, postback

I have panel in my HTML like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="cropPanel" runat="server">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h3 style="text-align:center; text-decoration:solid;">Before image: </h3>
        <img style="width:100%;" id="before" src="" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="X1" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="Y1" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="W1" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="H1" runat="server" />

    </div>

    <!-- After image -->
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h3 style="text-align:center; text-decoration:solid;">After image: </h3>
        <img style="width:100%;" id="after" src="" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="X2" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="Y2" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="W2" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="H2" runat="server" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

This is the logic for getting the cropped image new dimensions using jQuery/JavaScript like following:

```
$('#<%=before.ClientID%>').Jcrop({
    onSelect: SelectCropArea

});

function SelectCropArea(c) {
    $('#<%=X1.ClientID%>').val(parseInt(c.x1));
    $('#<%=Y1.ClientID%>').val(parseInt(c.y1));
    $('#<%=W1.ClientID%>').val(parseInt(c.w1));
    $('#<%=H1.ClientID%>').val(parseInt(c.h1));
}
$('#<%=after.ClientID%>').Jcrop({
    onSelect: SelectCropArea2
});

function SelectCropArea2(c) {
    $('#<%=X2.ClientID%>').val(parseInt(c.x2));
    $('#<%=Y2.ClientID%>').val(parseInt(c.y2));
    $('#<%=W2.ClientID%>').val(parseInt(c.w2));
    $('#<%=H2.ClientID%>').val(parseInt(c.h2));
}
```

And when I press the link button event:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkCrop" OnClick="linkCrop_Click" runat="server">Save & Upload</asp:LinkButton>
```

Code behind:

```
Rectangle CropAreaBefore = new Rectangle(Int32.Parse(X1.Value), Int32.Parse(Y1.Value), Int32.Parse(W1.Value), Int32.Parse(H1.Value));
Rectangle CropAreaAfter = new Rectangle(Int32.Parse(X2.Value), Int32.Parse(Y2.Value), Int32.Parse(W2.Value), Int32.Parse(H2.Value));

//The `X1/Y1/W1/H1 and X2/Y2/W2/H2 are empty
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Edit: I checked whether the values are set properly in jquery, they are, here's the pic showing it:

[image]

Comment: They are all runat server already @Lain

Comment: I think it's got something to do with the postback, but I just can't get the hold of it... You guys got any idea?

Comment: You sure all your HiddenField are getting populated after running SelectCropArea() ?

Comment: @RangaDewasinghe yeah I did a console.log after each time i crop the image on client side. I get results like: Object { x = , y  = } ...

Comment: P.S. For some weird reason I can't get to work the regular button event in panel... And I'm forced to use linkbutton...

Comment: Is Object { x = , y = }  or it should be Object { x1 = , y1 = } ? @user987

Comment: This second one: X1 = , Y1= etc etc...

Comment: Any ideas guys ??

Comment: I am still thinking this is not an issue in postback, can you check in the page source your hidden text boxes has values or not? @User987

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129699/discussion-between-user987-and-ranga-dewasinghe).

Comment: @RangaDewasinghe I updated my initial question with pic, the values seem to be set okay in jquery...

Comment: This is really odd... Theres absolutely no reason for the coordinates to be empty at all...